# Joomla 2.5 -Assign Article to Multiple User Groups

Tags: joomla2.5, usergroups

How can I assign single article to multiple user groups ? Is there any module for that ?

Answer (score -1):

When you create article you can choose access level (public, registered, special, etc). You can manage these levels in "users" component (top menu -> users -> access levels) and choose wchich user groups belongs to your custom access level.